# What is the relative path of a Resources.resx file with regards to the .exe?

Tags: .net, resources

I have a simple Console Application, and I have several configurable strings in the Resources.resx, but the binary is unable to find its Resources.resx when I do run it from Debug, or Release directory.

When I do run it from VS 2010, everything works fine.

Where should I locate that Resources.resx file?

I tried putting the Resources.resx with the ConsoleApplication.exe together, but no luck. Then, I created a folder called "Properties", as a subdirectory of the ConsoleApplication.exe path, and then the .resx file within it, but it didn't work neither.

Comment: Are you embedding them or linking them? embedding them means compiling them into a Class called Resources

Comment: @RuneFS:How can I change that?

Comment: Well that's kinda what it's there for if you simply want your data in a file why don't you just create your own file. But you Can simply Google resources.resx and the first link describes in detail how you Can use .resx